# Error reading a Trajectory File using Chemfiles library

Tags: c++, cmake, g++

I need to write a piece of cpp code that will read a trajectory file (.pdb or .dcd files). I have followed the steps on the homepage of [chemfiles](http://chemfiles.org/chemfiles/0.6.0/example.html) library to read in the file. I am getting an error about undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 (please see a piece of the error log below).

What I want: Able to read the .dcd/.pdb file using the chemfiles library (or any other suitable library to do so) - I need to access the coordinates of the atoms listed in the file.

Code that reproduces the error when compiled using the command below:

```
#include "/usr/local/include/chemfiles.hpp" //path to library on my mac

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    chemfiles::Trajectory testfile("test.dcd");
    return 1;
}
```

Code that compiles successfully in CLI using the command below:

```
#include "/usr/local/include/chemfiles.hpp" //path to library on my mac

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // chemfiles::Trajectory testfile("test.dcd");
    return 1;
}
```

Command to compile program:

```
g++-8 -fopenmp trial.cpp -o trial -lchemfiles -L /usr/local/lib
// I am using openmp because my original code is about parallelisation with openmp
```

Error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "chemfiles::Trajectory::Trajectory(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, char, 
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
  _main in ccnk7agz.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, 
std::__1::allocator<char> >::find(char, unsigned long) const", 
referenced from:
      file_open_info::parse(std::__1::basic_string<char, 
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, 
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, 
std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libchemfiles.a(Trajectory.cpp.o)
      split_comment(std::__1::basic_string<char, 
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&) in 
libchemfiles.a(LAMMPSData.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, 
std::__1::allocator<char> >::rfind(char, unsigned long) const", 
referenced from:
      file_open_info::parse(std::__1::basic_string<char,  
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, 
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, 
std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libchemfiles.a(Trajectory.cpp.o)
      chemfiles::SDFFormat::read(chemfiles::Frame&) in 
libchemfiles.a(SDF.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, 
std::__1::allocator<char> >::compare(unsigned long, unsigned long, char 
const*, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      file_open_info::parse(std::__1::basic_string<char, 
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, 
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, 
std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libchemfiles.a(Trajectory.cpp.o)
      chemfiles::Trajectory::Trajectory(std::__1::basic_string<char, 
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, char, 
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, 
std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libchemfiles.a(Trajectory.cpp.o)
      chemfiles::FormatFactory::register_format(chemfiles::FormatInfo, 
std::__1::function<std::__1::unique_ptr<chemfiles::Format, 
std::__1::default_delete<chemfiles::Format> > 
(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, 
std::__1::allocator<char> >, chemfiles::File::Mode, 
chemfiles::File::Compression)>) in libchemfiles.a(FormatFactory.cpp.o)
      chemfiles::Frame::guess_bonds()     in 
libchemfiles.a(Frame.cpp.o)
      chemfiles::FormatInfo::FormatInfo(std::__1::basic_string<char, 
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in 
libchemfiles.a(CSSR.cpp.o)
      chemfiles::FormatInfo::FormatInfo(std::__1::basic_string<char, 
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in 
libchemfiles.a(MMTF.cpp.o)
      chemfiles::MOL2Format::read(chemfiles::Frame&) in 
libchemfiles.a(MOL2.cpp.o)
      ...
```

Comment: How is CMake related with a problem (you use `cmake` as a tag)? According to the error message, it seems that your library is ABI incompatible with a compiler. Just google for "undefined reference to cxx11".

Comment: The library has been installed using cmake. There are various tags that can be set when installing using cmake - Maybe I did not set a flag correctly when installing using cmake? Thanks for the reply though, I'm gonna look for that now.

Comment: Firstly check which compiler has been used when build the library. Using **the same compiler** for build library and executable prevent such incompatibilities in most cases.